# Custom editor color palette colors are not appearing in the editor

Tags: functions, block-editor, color-picker

Below is the function to add my custom colors, the 'disable-custom-colors' is working properly, but the custom colors that I'm trying to add are not appearing in the editor. I have also tried clearing my cache and the issue persists.

```
function add_custom_gutenberg_color_palette() {
    add_theme_support( 'disable-custom-colors' );

    add_theme_support(
        'editor-color-palette',
        array(
            array(
                'name'  => esc_html__('Red', 'twentytwentyone-child'),
                'slug'  => 'red',
                'color' => '#E4D1D1',
            ),
            array(
                'name'  => esc_html__('Orange', 'twentytwentyone-child'),
                'slug'  => 'orange',
                'color' => '#E4DAD1',
            )
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'add_custom_gutenberg_color_palette' );
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that you're using a child theme of Twenty Twenty-One, which also [registers](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-content/themes/twentytwentyone/functions.php#L346) custom editor color palette using the same hook and priority (i.e. 10), so try using 11 or greater as the action's priority:

```php
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'add_custom_gutenberg_color_palette', 11 );
```

Comment: Yes that was it! Thank you!